# Rethinkdb append to array if exists

Tags: javascript, replace, insert, rethinkdb, nosql

In RethinkDB, I have a table `authors` with the following layout:

```
{
  id: 12,
  videos: [1,2,3]
}
```

Now I get new authors with objects like this:

```
{
  id: 12,
  videos: [4,5]
}
```

If the author now already exists, I want to append the new videos `4` and `5` to the list of videos.
If author not exists, just insert the document like it is.
My approach was the following, but it didn't work.

```
r.table('authors').getAll(4, 3, 2, 1, {index: 'id'})
    .replace(function(author, index) {
        return r.branch(
            author.eq(null),
            {
                id: index,
                videos: [1,2,3]
            },
            author
        );
    })
```

-> Response:

```
{
    "deleted": 0 ,
    "errors": 3 ,
    "first_error":  "Expected 2 arguments but found 1." ,
    "inserted": 0 ,
    "replaced": 0 ,
    "skipped": 0 ,
    "unchanged": 0
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is very good. It is just some syntax issue.

Given an author, if the author isn't existed, insert it, otherwise, append the video array, here is what I think of, using your logic:

```
var author = {
    id: 12,
  videos: [9, 10]
};

r.table('authors').insert(author).do(
    function (doc) {
        return r.branch(doc('inserted').ne(0),
          r.expr({inserted: 1}),
          r.table('authors').get(author["id"]).update(function(doc) {
            return {videos: doc('videos').union(author["videos"])}
          })
        )
    }
)
```

If the insert is sucesfully, it means we have no document with the same `id`, we don't have to do anything. Otherwise, we will update the document and append the videos into it.

To updare an array of multiple author, we can use `foreach` and `expr` to turn array into ReQL object. However, in this case, we use `bracket` to get field instead of using `[]` as in JavaScript object

```
var authors = [{
    id: 12,
    videos: [90, 91]
},{
    id: 14,
    videos: [1, 2]
}];

r.expr(authors).forEach(function(author) {

  return r.table('authors').insert(author).do(
    function (doc) {
        return r.branch(doc('inserted').ne(0),
          r.expr({inserted: 1}),
          r.table('authors').get(author("id")).update(function(doc) {
            return {videos: doc('videos').union(author("videos"))}
          })
        )
    }
  )

})
```

Comment: thanks, that r.expr(authors).forEach was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
r([4, 3, 2, 1]).foreach(function(id) {
  return r.table('authors').get(id).replace(function(row) {
    return r.branch(row.eq(null), {id: id, videos: [1, 2, 3]}, row);
  });
});
```

Comment: your answer was awesome, too, but I can only choose one as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

lambda for [replace](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/replace/) method has only 1 argument. But you are trying too pass 2 args: `author`, `index`.

Comment: Yes, but what would be a solution to the problem?